# jQuery - .on('click'.. doesn't work on new AJAX content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of people for an event, which is called through ajax together with the ID of the event, and put into a div.
(I can change which event will be showed with a select-list).

If I check a person off (checkbox after each person), they get a class of "removed". 
They are then hidden in the list.

```
$(this).hide();.
```

I also have a button called Show All, and when clicked, this code is called:

```
$(document).on('click', '#showAll', function () {
    $('.removed').toggle();
});
```

This works, until I change list. If I change list, nothing happens when the Show All-button is pressed. If I then change back to the previous event, it works as before.

So the problem is, the Show All-button is locked to the first event I use the button on, and then I am unable to use it when I switch events. It only works if I refresh the page.

I read somewhere to use event.preventDefault(); but it still doesn't work (and maybe it's not the solution at all). I have also tried to get the Show All-button with ajax and reload it every time I change event (as if it would break the connection to the current event), but it still doesn't work (and I really don't understand why with this solution).

**Edit:** I removed the unrelevant code and cleaned it up a bit. (And I noticed the ShowAll-button had a class and not an ID as I wrote before.

```
/* HTML for the button */
<td class="showAll button">Show All</td>

/* jQuery */

$('#eventID').change(function() { //Select-list

    eventID = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

    function check() { // To mark a person who has attended and give them a class of removed
        $('#allAttendees').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
            var email = $(this).val();
            var removed;

            removed = $(this).attr('name');

            $('#allAttendees tr[value="'+email+'"]').hide();
            $('#allAttendees tr.removed').hide();

            $.ajax({
                url: /* path */,
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'eventID=' + eventID + '&email=' + email + '&removed=' + removed,
                success: function(ADD) {
                    getAll();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function getAll() { // Gets the list of all persons for the event
        $.ajax({
            url: /* path */,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'eventID=' + eventID,
            success: function(getAttendieesData) {
                $('#attendies').html(getAttendieesData);

                check();
            }
        });     
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.showAll', function () { // Should hide/show all persons with the class removed, but only works on the first event I use it on
        $('.removed').toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: could you provide a complete fiddle of your prob?

Comment: You need to show your HTML. We only know half of what's going on here.

Comment: The code above should cause the event to be handled even after the change. Something else is going on. Please provide a reproducible test case.

Comment: Most likely, your "change" is causing the loss of either the #showAll id or the .removed class.

Comment: Please add more information to your question. With the current information it will be impossible to answer it definitively.

Comment: Do you by chance have multiple `show-all` buttons.  One per event?  If so, that is your problem.  You can't have duplicate `id`s.  Change to using a class.

Comment: I posted the code. Hope it is enough